# Transform text from DB

Tags: php

I have an email template like this in my DB:

```
<p style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px;'>
    Gentile {name} la password del tuo account &egrave; stata modificata correttamente.<br/>
    Di seguito i tuoi nuovi dati di accesso:
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style='width: 70px'>Username: </td>
        <td style='width: 70px'>{$email}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='width: 70px'>Password: </td>
        <td style='width: 70px'>{password}</td>
        </td>
</table>
<p style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 14px;'>
    A presto<br/>
    Lo staff di {APP_NAME}
</p>
```

I want to replace all the strings contained within `{}` (i.e. `{name}` ) with the relative value.
I have created a simple function that will take an `array` and should transform the strings. But for some reasons it does not work..

```
return transform($body, array('{name}' => 'Diego', 'APP_NAME' => 'Blahbla', '{username}' => 'email@email'));

    function transform($text, $replace) {
        if (is_array($replace)) {
            foreach ($replace as $key => $value)
                $str = str_replace($key, $value, $text);
            return $str;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$text = str_replace($key, $value, $text);
return $text;
```

you store the result from `str_replace` in `$str` and so you return only the last element

Answer (score 0):

I've made this function

```
public function MsgHTML($message, $data=array())
{
    if (!empty($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
            $message = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $val, $message);
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

Try this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop as [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can work with arrays:

```
function transform($text, $replace) {
    if (is_array($replace)) {
        return str_replace(arrar_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```